# PHP - Do this, and if the next part meets this criteria also do this

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm quite new to PHP, but have no idea how to word this question.

I want to return a coloured circle if the colour has been selected elsewhere.

So if silver has been ticked, show a silver circle.

If silver and gold have been ticked, show both.

There must be an easier way to code the below, instead of having to create lots of seperate if statements and call a variable each time?

elseif's wouldn't work here from my understanding.

Forgive me for my naivety!

The code I've written below:

```
    <?php

            // for iphone   
            $colours_available = get_field('iphone_colours_available');


            // check
            if( $colours_available && in_array('silver', $colours_available) ): ?>


              <div class="colour-circle-title"><p>Silver</p></div>


        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php

            // vars 
            $colours_available = get_field('iphone_colours_available');


            // check
            if( $colours_available && in_array('gold', $colours_available) ): ?>



              <div class="colour-circle-title"><p>Gold</p></div>





        <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: If you just iterate over (try foreach()) the array returned by get_field('iphone_colours_available') you can display each color that shows up no "if's" needed. Unless all the colors being returned are not supposed to all show but I assume it's filtering out only available ones.

Comment: Thanks! this method worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can iterate through your `$colours_available` array, and then use `ucwords()` to camel-case your p-tag's text:

```
<?php $colours_available = get_field('iphone_colours_available'); ?>
<?php foreach($colours_available  as $color) :; ?> 
    <div class="colour-circle-title"><p><?php echo ucwords($color); ?></p></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note: If you don't need to use the `$colours_availble` array elsewhere, you could eliminate that line and replace it wtih `get_field('iphone_colours_available')` in the loop.  Also, this solution does not address sorting, which your previous solution does.  For that, I would recommend looking at [PHP's sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), specifically `uasort`, `uksort`, and `usort`